# SCSS check for CSS custom var property

Tags: sass, css-variables

How do I conditionally apply a mixin if `--my-custom-var` is present? For example:

```
.test {
  @if var(--my-custom-var) {
     @include someExampleMixin()
  }

  @if var(--another-custom-var) {
     @include someExampleMixin()
  }
}
```

I don't care what the value of the `--my-custom-var` is but just want to check its existence.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is possible. Sass doesn't do any evaluation of regular CSS variables.

Answer (score 3):

Sass has introduced the `variable-exists()` function already in alpha. Be aware that *Sass* can only check for *Sass* variables. Therefor **if** you'd really want to use CSS variables you need to define the content of your *CSS* variable inside a *Sass* variable, for example `$sassVar: /* content */;` `--cssVar: $sassVar;`. Be also aware that the `@if` statement must be *inside* a `@mixin` or a `@function` to work. I posted a working example below, but here is aslo my [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/YzwMNVJ) since Stack doesn't compile Sass.

**Note**:

- I used `"null"` inside my `$var` which basically expresses that there
  is **no** content within this variable, you can pass whatever you
  want it won't affect the outcome unless you remove or change the actual
  variable.
- You can use multiple `@if` statements which I commented out in this example, **but** there should always follow an `@else` statement.

```css
$var: null;

:root {
  --someVar: $var;
}

@mixin checkForVariable {
  @if variable-exists(var){
    body {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
  //  @if variable-exists() {
  //    ...
  //  }
  //  @if variable-exists() {
  //    ...
  //  }
  @else {
    body {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }
}

@include checkForVariable;
```